Python requests.get method stuck on audio streams
requests.get gets stuck on streams, like, for example,
https://centova.radios.com.pt/proxy/476?mp=/stream
https://nl.digitalrm.pt:8216/stream

Is there any way to detect this automatically and abort? I don't know beforehand what kinds of addresses I'm visiting. I was expecting get to time out.
I've tried connect and read timeouts, but they don't do anything...
from requests import get
response = get("https://centova.radios.com.pt/proxy/476?mp=/stream", timeout = 5)

I wish there was an absolute timeout.

There is a stream argument that can give you access in chunks. You can close it down whenever you want. https://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/advanced/#body-content-workflow
